# Anova. Homoscedasticity not respected

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I'd like to perform an ANOVA with a normally distributed response variables and several explanatory variables. Some of the explanatory variables are continuous and some are categorical (factor(..)).

```
aov(a~numeric(b) + factor(c ) + numeric(d) + factor(e))
```

The residuals of this model are perfectly normally distributed but the assumption of homoscedasticity is not respected. What can I do?

- Welch correction?

  - Does it work for multiple way ANOVA? How can we perform such a thing with R?
- ordered logic model?

  - I tried the function `polr` (in R) but I get an error message saying that the response should be a factor
- Friedman test?

  - I tried but I got an error message saying that the formula is incorrect (although it is exactly the same as for aov(..))
- Kruskal.wallis?

  - It works only for one-way Anova I think.

---

Update

```
m = aov(myFormula, myData)
plot(y=residuals(m), x=m$fit)
abline(lm(residuals(m)~m$fit))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that with continuous predictors, `aov` fits a general linear model - usually called regression rather than ANOVA, even though you may want to look at an ANOVA table.

Comment: Is there an apparent relationship between the variance of the residuals and the fitted values?

Comment: @Scortchi Should I check this on this kind of plot: `plot(residuals(m), predict(m))` ? (where `m = aov(myFormula, myData)`) or doing this: `summary(lm(predict(m)~residuals(m)))`? Or something else?

Comment: You should plot residuals against fits. It may suggest a useful transformation or a mean-variance relationship to use in an estimating-equation approach with robust standard errors. See [robust regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression) & [sandwich estimators](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50778/sandwich-estimator-intuition) for standard errors.

Comment: @Scortchi See my update post.

Comment: It's not gross heteroskedasticity. Investigate outliers & try sandwich estimators for the standard errors to see the difference.

Comment: I don't fully understand how I can investigate further the violation of the assumption. I did `sandwich(m)` and `vcovHC(m, type = "HC")` and I get a 30*30 matrix. What does it mean? Thanks a lot for your help @Scortchi

Comment: Well read up on sandwich estimators, don't just type `sandwich` in R! It's giving you a robust estimate of the variance-covariance matrix for your model's coefficients, from which you can calculate their standard errors; all without assuming homoskedasticity of the error terms.