# Intuition behind White's Estimators/ Heteroscedasticity-consistent Standard Errors

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-error, heteroscedasticity, intuition

For a medical study I am trying to understand the intuition behind heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors. I know that it can be used, when in OLS regression residuals are heteroscedastic.

By text books only provide a rather technical explanation for it. Can someone provide an explanation for the intuitition behind it? It would be nice if some could explain how White standard errors work without a lot of formulas.

Comment: Huber and Eicker are other names used.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50778/sandwich-estimator-intuition?rq=1